# Run Script On A (Music)Keyboard

Tags: linux-kernel, usb-drive

I am asking this here because I believe my (musical) keyboard, a KORG PA4X, runs a form of linux kernel. The keyboard has a usb slot to access different beats and styles. Is there a way to code a usb drive that when it gets plugged in, it runs a script on the keyboard? (Say, something simple like checking the device serial number, or memory capacity etc...)

Comment: I see some people got pretty far hacking into the [Kronos](https://marcan.st/2016/06/hacking-and-upgrading-the-korg-kronos/) . What you say may be doable by some `udev` rule, but in order to do it you would need access into the korg's linux.

Comment: If a Linux (or other GNU-GPL licensed SW) is realy inside, you have first to look for the sources and then address your question directly to developer team.

Comment: Good luck. I hope you find something, and have fun. However please not the difference between Linux and Gnu/Linux. Linux is just the kernel, it is in many embedded devices, and in android. Gnu/Linux is on operating system.